# Flickering issue with antd

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using the Ant Design components for some interfaces in a React App but I'm noticing an issue with Modals and Tooltips. Usually when the modal is empty or is simple - e.g has only a text it is going to show properly but in case there are more elements on it (on production scenario) it flickers.

You can visually watch the flickering issue here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ODsj-aGz6saHJLXLI7sJaesgHKKPrvD2/view

Hope to get some answers :-) Thank you!
The visibleRequest state variable is triggered true by a button in the interface.
EDIT: As requested here's my code:

```
renderRequests=()=>{
        const data = [
            {name:"Request #1",description:"Request description",status:"0"},
            {name:"Request #1",description:"Request description",status:"1"},
            {name:"Request #1",description:"Request description",status:"2"}
        ];
        const handleOk = ()=>{
            console.log("Submitted");
            this.setState({visibleRequest:false})
        }
        const handleCancel = ()=>{
            this.setState({visibleRequest:false})
        }
        return(
            <div style={{overflowY:"scroll"}}>
            <Modal
                title="Submit new request"
                visible={this.state.visibleRequest}
                onOk={handleOk}
                onCancel={handleCancel}
                >
                <Input placeholder="Title"/>
                <Input.TextArea placeholder="Description"/>
                <DatePicker/>
            </Modal>
                <List 
                    dataSource={data}
                    renderItem={item=>{
                        return(
                            <List.Item>
                                <List.Item.Meta
                                title={item.name}
                                description={item.description}
                                />
                                {item.status==1?<Tooltip title="Request approved">
                                <Icon type="check-circle" theme="twoTone" twoToneColor="#52c41a" />
                                </Tooltip>:
                                item.status==2?<Icon type="close-circle" theme="twoTone" twoToneColor="#7F1C43" />:<Icon type="ellipsis" theme="outlined" />}
                            </List.Item>
                        )
                }}/>
                <Pagination total={20}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Could you share some code? It'll be easier to understand and debug if you give codepen which reproduces the issue. 
It seems to work fine in the [docs](https://ant.design/components/modal/). Most likely an issue with how you handle the visibility of the modal from your state.

Comment: OK Sorry! I've updated the post with the code now. :-)

Comment: This code looks fine. Nothing here to show the flickering behavior. Can you please reproduce the issue in a codepen/fiddle/git ? I'll take a look at it then. 

PS : the video you posted isn't of this code. I hope that was intentional. The video has the "write a new message" modal and the code has "submit a new request modal"

Comment: Oh sorry! I wasn't exact. This is the code of the "request modal" while the one in the video is the "Message modal". It has the issue as the one in the video. OK I'll try to reproduce this in the codepen.

Comment: Thanks. Just wanted to make sure we are on the same page.